# How to explain this strange phenomenon about pointer of slice in Golang?

Tags: pointers, go

In the code below:

```
s4 := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
sp4 := &s4
sp5 := &((*sp4)[1:])
```

I want to get the pointer a slice of `s4[1:]` as s5, but this cause an error:

```
cannot take the address of (*sp4)[1:]
```

But if I write like this:

```
s4 := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
sp4 := &s4
s5 := (*sp4)[1:]
sp5 := &s5
```

It works!

I have made some tests, and found that when I change *sp5, s4 change as while. That's what I just need.

But **why** cannot I write `sp5 := &((*sp4)[1:])`?

Comment: Some things in Go are literally _unaddressable_: You simply cannot take their address because the language spec _forbids_ it.

Comment: This: `(*sp4)[1:]` is a slice expression, it results in a slice value. This value may not have a memory address as it is not in a variable, it may just live in processor registers until you store it in a variable. To give the compiler the freedom to store it wherever it sees best, the spec does not allow taking its address.